# GenServer doesn't trap_exit when started with start_link

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, gen-server

I found that when trying to trap exit signal, starting a GenServer with `GenServer.start` then `Process.link` the pid has very different outcome than running `GenServer.start_link`.

Here's the experiment code I used to demonstrate the problem:

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmodule Server do
    def init(_) do
      Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
      {:ok, nil}
    end
    def handle_info({:EXIT, from, reason}, _) do
      IO.inspect({:kill_signal, from, reason})
      {:noreply, nil}
    end
  end

  def foo() do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
    # version 1
    {:ok, pid} = GenServer.start_link(Server, nil)

    # version 2
    # {:ok, pid} = GenServer.start(Server, nil)
    # Process.link(pid)

    # print process info
    IO.inspect({self(), pid, Process.info(pid)})

    Process.exit(pid, :reason)

    :timer.sleep(200)
  end
end

Foo.foo
```

With version 1, the EXIT signal cause the `Server` to exit without being caught in its `handle_info` block, but with version 2, the signal was correctly intercepted and processed in `handle_info` block, and therefore `Server` is not terminated. I also notice that the `Process.info` of these two ways to start a GenServer are identical.

I tried the same thing with `spawn_link` and `spawn`, but they all behaves as expected - EXIT signal all being caught - there's no difference:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def loop do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
    receive do
      msg -> IO.inspect(msg)
    end
    loop
  end

  def foo() do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)
    # version 1
    pid = spawn_link(&loop/0)

    # version 2
    # pid = spawn(&loop/0)
    # Process.link(pid)

    # print process info
    IO.inspect({self(), pid, Process.info(pid)})

    Process.exit(pid, :reason)

    :timer.sleep(200)
  end
end

Foo.foo
```

By the way I'm using Elixir 1.8.1 on Erlang/OTP 21, if it matters.

I want to know what causes the difference in behaviors, is this a bug or by design, and how I can trap EXIT correctly if I want to call start+link atomically.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mrallen1/806fe5506132260574af33e99dadd499

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`handle_info` is not being called because the one sending the exit signal is the parent process. GenServer and all other behaviours handles the parent exit signal and always shuts down when the parent does, mainly because if you are in a supervision tree and your supervisor shuts down, you want to terminate immediately too as at that moment all bets are off. If you replace this:

```
Process.exit(pid, :reason)
```

By:

```
spawn fn -> Process.exit(pid, :reason) end
```

You can see `handle_info` called as another process is sending the exit signal.

Comment: Thank you, I also found the document here: http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-4.8.2/doc/design_principles/spec_proc.html

Comment: Thank you for the clarification; IMHO this snippet would make a lot of sense in the documentation / guides on how OTP process model differs from “orphan” processes.